# python barchart grouped by 3 variables

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I try to plot a bar chart to show 3 variables: count of different building types accumulated by each player by 3 game types (lost, won, average). I wanted buildings of different types to be grouped for each player and then in one column counts for games of different types. My problem is that smaller values are hidden behind bigger values and not visible.

It's best seen on the picture. For roads and citites the chart looks good, however for settlements only lost game count is visible. In won games players usually have less settlements, so count of settlements from lost games has covered the count from won game.

Is there a way to move smaller values to the front? (keeping colors and legend)

If it's not possible, is there a way to show these three variables in one plot in readable way?

My data looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    pn_name=["player1", "player2", "player3", "player4"]*3,
    building_type=["settlements"]*4 +  ["cities"]*4 +  ["roads"]*4,
    won_game=[0.,1.35, 1.36, 1.36, 0., 3.48, 3.48, 3.47,0.,  8.27, 8.25, 8.33],
    avg_game=[1.81, 1.38, 1.39, 1.38, 0.5, 2.77, 2.76, 2.77, 7.75, 6.72, 6.7, 6.76],
    lost_game =[1.81, 1.4, 1.4, 1.39, 0.5, 2.41,2.42, 2.42, 7.75, 5.93,5.95, 5.96] ))
```

and so far I have this plot:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x="pn_name", y="won_game", hue="building_type", data=df, 
              hue_order = ["settlements", "cities", "roads"],
           palette = sns.xkcd_palette(["windows blue", "amber",  "raspberry"]))
sns.barplot(x="pn_name", y="avg_game", hue="building_type", data=df,
              hue_order = ["settlements", "cities", "roads"],
           palette = sns.xkcd_palette(["grey blue", "pumpkin",  "reddish pink"]))
sns.barplot(x="pn_name", y="lost_game", hue="building_type", data=df,  
              hue_order = ["settlements", "cities", "roads"],
               palette = sns.xkcd_palette(["light blue grey", "pale gold", "rose pink"]))

handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()

handles = [handles[0], handles[3], handles[6], handles[1], handles[4], handles[7], handles[2], handles[5], handles[8]]

labels = ['settlements - won game', 'settlements - avg game','settlements - lost game',
         'cities - won game', 'cities - avg game','cities - lost game',
         'roads - won game','roads - avg game','roads - lost game']
plt.legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., title = "building type")
plt.show()
```

which gives me:

[image: bar chart]